# Matrix to Matrix Votes conversion

Tags: r, matrix

I have output of classification algorithm in the form of probabilities. they look like:

```
> head(testProb)
     B    U
1 0.98 0.02
2 0.80 0.20
3 0.14 0.86
4 0.91 0.09
5 0.25 0.75
6 0.86 0.14
```

When I checked the class, it was:

```
> class(testProb)
[1] "matrix" "votes"
```

If I take a subset of it, for example, I want 1st column:

> a <- testProb[,1]

```
> head(a)
   1    2    3    4    5    6 
0.98 0.80 0.14 0.91 0.25 0.86
> class(a)
[1] "numeric"
```

I have another such classification output matrix but it has not the class of "matrix" "votes". How can I convert it into "matrix" "votes"? So that when I take subset then I get the values in the form when I took subset before.

```
> head(prediction)
             B          U
[1,] 0.9413505 0.05864955
[2,] 0.8758474 0.12415256
[3,] 0.2271516 0.77284845
[4,] 0.9227356 0.07726441
[5,] 0.1838987 0.81610128
[6,] 0.9253403 0.07465969
> class (prediction)
[1] "matrix"
> a <- prediction[,1]
> head(a)
[1] 0.9413505 0.8758474 0.2271516 0.9227356 0.1838987 0.9253403
> class(a)
[1] "numeric"
```

In this case as well I want `a` as I get in the first case. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which package are you using ? `votes` is not a class/type part of base R as far as I can tell.

Comment: This votes matrix is the output of randomForest and the plain matrix is the output of naiveBayes.

Comment: @tensibai, I am just interested in subsetting that matrix in such a way that I get the index value (if I'm not calling it wrongly) of every value.

Comment: In this cases: `names(a) <- 1:nrow(prediction)` should do. (But I don't get how it would be useful later)

Comment: What I mean is, it's already subseted in the same way, one is named vector (testprob), the second is an anonymous vector, both are numeric. Just one have names for each value, which is kind of useless here as it's the index.

Comment: @Tensibai I was actually trying to make ROC Curve from these values and as far as I have seen for ROCR package, the indeces does matter because when I give vector without indeces it doesn't give the right output. Thanks for the answer. You can write it in proper answer, I will accept it, as it has solved my problem.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow if no-one tackle your problem before. (It seems the root problem is the graphing, not naming the vector, but maybe this is the right solution, I don't know)

Comment: @Newbie: to make a ROC, you need the truth labels corresponding to the predictions. Then see `?prediction`, `?performance`, and `plot.performance` in the `ROCR` package.